# how to center align the submit and cancel buttons on the editgridrow popup screen

Tags: jqgrid, font-size, popupwindow

I am using jqgrids editgridrow function to add/edit records.How do I position the submit and cancel button on the popup to center and how do i reduce the fontsize of the labels in the  popup.I couldnot find a way to do this as there are no inbuilt properties for this and I donot intend to use custom dialog box. Does anyone know a workaround?

Thanks,
Anita

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't use `direction: "rtl"` option in jqGrid then usage of CSS

```css
.ui-jqdialog-content td.EditButton { text-align: center }
```

should solve the problem. See [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/CenterButtonsInEditForm.htm) which displays

[image]

I don't understand why you should reduce the fontsize of the labels. The font used per default in jqGrid is already very small on my taste. Nevertheless the CSS style like

```css
.ui-jqdialog .ui-jqdialog-content .CaptionTD { font-size: 8px }
```

could be used. See [the next demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/CenterButtonsInEditForm1.htm) which displays

[image]

Comment: thanks for you reply. The font-size issue is resolved however I am not able to set the buttons to the center using this css. I guess it must be because I am using editGridRow to open the add/edit dialog

Comment: @Anita: You are welocome! The code of my demo uses `navGrid` which uses `editGridRow` internally. So it should work. I suppose that you placed `.ui-jqdialog-content td.EditButton { text-align: center }` on the wrong place. You should either place it **after** "ui.jqgrid.css" or you have to use more long CSS selector like `.ui-jqdialog .ui-jqdialog-content td.EditButton { text-align: center }` instead of `.ui-jqdialog-content td.EditButton { text-align: center }`

Comment: It worked!!! just used the long CSS selector and worked like a charm.. :) thanks a lot :)